# JQuery number library always returns 0 when converting

Tags: javascript, jquery

My program performs an AJAX call and depending on the returned value, it will fill or clear an `input` field initialized using the JQuery's number library.

```
$('input#total').number(true, 2);

....
$("form#submit").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(json) {
            var total = $("#total")

            if(json.total == null) {
                total.val(null)
                // total.val(undefined)
                // total.val("")
                // total.val(" ")
                // total.val("asdasdasdsad")
            }
            else {
                total.val(json.total)
            }
        }
        ...
    })

    return false
})
```

The program is functional, it enters to the appropriate `if` or `else` block. The problem is it sets the field to `0.00` regardless whether if you pass `null`, or an empty string, as long as it was non-number. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: What behaviour do you want to have?

Comment: @Rory What I expect is that if I set it to empty (say, `...val("")`), it will clear the text field.

Comment: Can you add a link to the number library you're using. There seems to be several available.

Comment: It's [version 2.1.5](https://github.com/customd/jquery-number).

Comment: have you parse json? `var json = jQuery.parseJSON(json);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `prop value` to `""`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://opensource.teamdf.com/number/jquery.number.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input#total').number(true, 2);
 var total=$("#total");
 total.val(30);
 total.prop("value","");
     
});

</script>

Total:<input id="total" type="text">
```